# How to estimate the entropy of a distribution on a power set?

Tags: st.statistics, it.information-theory, entropy, estimation-theory

Given a probability distribution $(X,p)$, its entropy is defined as $H=-\sum_{x\in X} p(x)\log p(x)$.

Given a sample of observations $x_n,n=1..N$, one can estimate $p(x)=\frac{\#\{i:x_i=x\}}{N}$ and thus $H$.

Suppose, however, that $X=P(B)$ the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of set $B$ and the observations are subsets of $B$: $x_n\subset B$ and the number of observations $\#B=k\ll N\ll 2^k=\#P(B)$.
E.g., $k=50$ and $N=10^4$.

I.e., there are not enough observations to estimate the probability of every separate subset.

**How would I estimate the entropy of the distribution?**

E.g., one can define a probability distribution on $B$ as

\begin{align}
 m(b)&=\sum_{x\ni b}p(x) \\ 
 M &= \sum_{b\in B} m(b) \\
 p_B(b) &= \frac{m(b)}{M}.
\end{align}

**What can be said about entropy of $(X=P(B),p)$ based on the entropy of $(B,p_B)$?** 
(the latter is easy to estimate based on the sample).

Comment: Is it important to the structure of the distribution that the observations are subsets? If we just think of the observations as integers between $1$ and $2^k$, then this sounds very hard: every distribution that is uniform on $\Omega(N^2)$ supports will look the same (no repeated samples), so distinguishing support size of $N^2$ from $2^k$ sounds impossible to me (but their entropies are very far apart).

Comment: @usul: yes, it is the critical point

Comment: @sds are you saying that every observed count is 1

Comment: @guest: I am saying that the structure of X as the power set is important for applications.

Comment: @sds, then maybe you can make some assumption about the distribution in terms of the subsets. Otherwise it may not be doable....

Comment: It's not relevant for **computing** the entropy that the power set structure is useful for applications. Since you haven't indicated that the power set structure has any constraints, then as @usul points out it's equivalent to having an arbitrary collection of integers in a larger set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the power-set structure helps you estimate entropy better.
The following extreme cases all give the same entropy for $p_B$, but entropy of the power set observation ranges from 0 to $N$ (the full range).

- Extreme case 1, if you only observe $B$, your entropy $H(X)$ is zero, while entropy of $p_B$ is maximum, $\log_2(N)$.
- Extreme case 2, if you observe $\{1\}, \ldots, \{N\}$ uniformly, entropy is $H(X)=\log_2(N)$, and entropy of $p_B$ is also $\log_2(N)$.
- Extreme case 3, if you observe all subsets equally likely, entropy $H(X)$ is $N$, while the entropy of $p_B$ is $\log_2(N)$

If entropy of $p_B$ is very small, that might restrict the maximum possible entropy for the power set observation, but I do not see an inequality. Even if there's an inequality, I don't think it can be tight.

As @guest suggested, using generic entropy estimators that perform well in the undersampled regime might be the best bet. @guest suggested my paper (thanks!), [here are some more choices](http://memming.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/a-guide-to-discrete-entropy-estimators/).

Answer (score 1):

This [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0328) explains entropy estimation without distribution estimation in the undersampled regime.

Comment: thanks, but the paper does not use the power set structure.

Comment: and code for the paper: https://github.com/pillowlab/PYMentropy

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather use a frequentist method (instead of the Bayesian approach described above), then a recent paper (that also reviews the literature on this) is [this one](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v31/clifford13a.pdf).